# videojs object has no method addEvent

Tags: api, html5-video

I've got videojs installed and working for playback of videos, however when I try to use the API I am hitting some issues

For example:

```
_V_("video").ready(function() {
   v = this
   v.play()
 }
```

Works as expected, playing the video once everything has loaded.

However, tracking a click on the play event thus:

```
_V_("video").ready(function() {
   v = this
   v.addEvent('play', function() { console.log('play') })
 }
```

Gives me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'addEvent'
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong as I am following the API docs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Video.js 4.0, addEvent was replace by ['on'](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api.md#events).

```
v.on('play', fn);
```

Comment: I was just about to point this out too (after an hour or so of banging my head against my desk) - it would definitely be worth updating the docs ;)